# Making pure css image slider responsive

Tags: css, responsive-design, responsive

The following pure css slider is working well, but I need to make it responsive. I've tried replacing the pixel-based sizes with percentages and with vw, but it doesn't line up. I'd be grateful for any ideas.

Here's the html:

```
<section class="slideshow">
  <div class="slideshow-container slide">
    <img src="images/anim/home-animation1.jpg" alt="pills">
    <img src="images/anim/home-animation2.jpg" alt="scientist"> 
    <img src="images/anim/home-animation3.jpg" alt="chemical structure">
    <img src="images/anim/proudmembermassbio.jpg" alt="proud member of MassBio"> </div>
</section>
```

And the css:

```
/*general styles*/

html { box-sizing: border-box; }
*, *:before, *:after { box-sizing: inherit; }

/* SLIDESHOW STYLES */
.slideshow-container {
    width: 1400px; /* the entire "stage" */
    font-size: 0;
    transition: 1s ease;
    height: 315px;
}
.slideshow-container:hover { animation-play-state: paused; }
.slideshow { /* the visible "stage" */
    width: 350px;
    margin: 1rem auto -1rem;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: solid 1px white;
}
img, .text-container {
    width: 350px;
    height: auto;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    text-align: center;
}
.text-container { /* for text slides */
    height: 195px;
    position: relative;
}
.slide { animation: slide 10s ease infinite; }

@keyframes slide {  
    0% { transform: translateX(0%); }
    12.5% { transform: translateX(0%); }
    25% { transform: translateX(-25%); }
    37.5% { transform: translateX(-25%); }
    50% { transform: translateX(-50%); }
    62.5% { transform: translateX(-50%); }
    75% { transform: translateX(-75%); }
    87.5% { transform: translateX(-75%); }
    99% { transform: translateX(-75%); }
    100% { transform: translateX(0); }
}
.p {
    margin-top: 140px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Please add a working fiddle.

Comment: I'm sorry, this is my first post on SO and I don't know what a fiddle is. I did a search but couldn't come up with a definition. Help?

Comment: Figured it out, I think.

https://jsfiddle.net/sec55/np2784h6/#&togetherjs=nyCvVSSxSi

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is too late for the user that posted this question, but can be helpful for someone else that want a pure responsive CSS slider.

I have created a [working example in this CodePen](https://codepen.io/riccardo-andreatta/pen/rNxyYOM) that is working as requested using percentages for widths and in the animation, and for this reason it is responsive and works really well in each resolutions.

All the main solution to have the responsiveness is here:

```
slider__container {
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    animation: 30s slide infinite;
    font-size: 0;
    width: 1000%; /* because I am using 10 slides */
}
```

The width should be calculated accordingly to how many slides are there in the slider: `slides x 100%` (slides times 100%, in my example 1000%).